# MySQL Query Execution Time Comparison

Tags: mysql, performance, database-performance

i am doing one select qry in my mysql database which contains " order by field desc".
I get the resultset within 16 minutes.

Now in the same qry i put  "order by field desc limit  5" to get the first 5 records..
But my qry is running for more than 20 minutes.

How can i make the execution faster?
Any Ideas?

Thanks-
jithkaran

Answer (score 0):

try by using top command in your select query

```
select top(5) * from table order by field desc
```

Comment: Hi,i used   " select top(5) * from CIRCLEDETAILS ORDER BY CIRCLE_ID DESC "  but getting error like "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from CIRCLEDETAILS ORDER BY CIRCLE_ID DESC' at line 1
"

Comment: what version of sql version you are using

Comment: mysql version isServer version: 5.1.36-community MySQL Community Server